# Proper mocking and testing of interactor class in Android

Tags: android, junit, mockito, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a bit problem setting up proper unit tests for my interactor classes in my android app. These classes is where I have "business logic" of my app.

Here is one such class:

```
public class ChangeUserPasswordInteractor {

    private final FirebaseAuthRepositoryType firebaseAuthRepositoryType;

    public ChangeUserPasswordInteractor(FirebaseAuthRepositoryType firebaseAuthRepositoryType) {
        this.firebaseAuthRepositoryType = firebaseAuthRepositoryType;
    }

    public Completable changeUserPassword(String newPassword){
        return firebaseAuthRepositoryType.getCurrentUser()
                .flatMapCompletable(firebaseUser -> {
                        firebaseAuthRepositoryType.changeUserPassword(firebaseUser, newPassword);
                        return Completable.complete();
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

Here is a test I wrote:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class ChangeUserPasswordInteractorTest {

    @Mock
    FirebaseAuthRepositoryType firebaseAuthRepositoryType;
    @Mock
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    @InjectMocks
    ChangeUserPasswordInteractor changeUserPasswordInteractor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler(schedulerCallable -> Schedulers.trampoline());
    }


    @Test
    public void changeUserPassword() {
        Mockito.when(firebaseAuthRepositoryType.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(Observable.just(firebaseUser));
        Mockito.when(firebaseAuthRepositoryType.changeUserPassword(firebaseUser, "test123")).thenReturn(Completable.complete());
        changeUserPasswordInteractor.changeUserPassword("test123")
                .test()
                .assertSubscribed()
                .assertNoErrors()
                .assertComplete();
    }
}
```

Problem here I am having is that this test completes with no errors, even If I change the password from "test123" on changeUserPassword invokation to something else, or if I in the mock return "Completable.onError(new Throwable())".

I can't understand this behavior. Any suggestions how to set up the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your `flatMapCompletable` always returns `Completable.complete()`

it should be :

`firebaseAuthRepositoryType.changeUserPassword(firebaseUser, newPassword);`

so :

```
public Completable changeUserPassword(String newPassword){
            return firebaseAuthRepositoryType.getCurrentUser()
                    .flatMapCompletable(firebaseUser -> 
                        firebaseAuthRepositoryType.changeUserPassword(firebaseUser, newPassword));
        }
```

Comment: I see! Thanks. If I may ask, now that I corrected the return in the method in the interactor, is the test method I wrote a "correct way" to test this class? Or do you have any suggestions/links that could help me better test it?

Comment: You are correctly verifying the use case, but in reality you've just tested your mocks, not any real behaviour/business logic. The only thing of value is to verify mock interactions i.e `verify(firebaseAuthRepositoryType).getCurrentUser()`

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to better testing this/similar Interactor classes?

Comment: This class doesn't hold any state, and delegates to other objects, which you have mocked the behaviour of. As said you can only test mock invocations.  Sometimes that is all that is required. Classes that have behaviour for example, a class that takes in a string and manipulates the string and returns a result string can be tested as this subject under test performs the behaviour. Usually Classes have a mixture of their own behaviour with mocked behaviour - the mocked behaviour lets you control external behaviour to reveal behavioural problems with the class under test.